# Uso de $_session con jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Estoy intentando esconder un php usando `$_SESSION` pero parece que no pasa del primer archivo. Acá muestro mis archivos:

**ajax.php**

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var value = $('#valor').val()

    $.ajax({
             type: "POST", 
             url: "salvar.php", 
             data: {valor: value},
             success: function(response) { 
                 console.log(response); 
             }
    }); 
});
```

**salvar.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['valor'] = $_POST['valor']; 
?>
```

**query.php**

```
<?php
    session_start(); 

    if (isset($_SESSION['valor'])){ echo 'si'};
    else {echo 'nop'};
?>
```

Si pongo un `echo` en salvar me muestra la variable en la respuesta del ajax, pero si dejo el echo del query no sucede nada, que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si seteas `$_SESSION['valor']` cómo podrías recuperar esa llave mediante `$_SESSION['tarjeta']`? tienen que ser consistentes entre sí

Comment: Siempre puedes [edit] tus publicaciones.